# How to format headers and footers in poemscol

Tags: fancyhdr

I have used fancyhdr in the past, no problem, but, with poemscol, I am unable to format Headers or Footers as I wish, the default style persists. Thus, how to re-set headers and footers if using poemscol

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to redefine the page style called `main` or the style called `fancy`. Just changing the header won't work, because many commands restore the style to `main`. The definitions of the two styles are the same. (I don't remember why I designed two styles.)

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhfoffset[RO,LE]{\headoffsetlength}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\small\textrm{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\small\textrm{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\hfil{\small{\em \volumeheadervalue}}\hfil}
\fancyhead[CE]{\hfil{\small{\em \leftheadervalue}}\hfil}
\fancyfoot[CE]{{\small \botmark}\hfil}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\hfil{\small \botmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhfoffset[RO,LE]{\headoffsetlength}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\small\textrm{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\small\textrm{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\hfil{\small{\em \volumeheadervalue}}\hfil}
\fancyhead[CE]{\hfil{\small{\em \leftheadervalue}}\hfil}
\fancyfoot[CE]{{\small \botmark}\hfil}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\hfil{\small \botmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very kindly for the answers suggested. The first does not solve my problem, but I shall persist in trying to work with redesigning the styles as shewn in the latter response. Poemscol is a very useful macro and, in general, a delight to use. Thanks again.